# Strong parameters for different controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm creating a controller in Rails, and I'm looking for ways to have different strong parameters for different controller methods

In update and new actions, I would want to require `post`

```
params.require(:post).permit(:body, :is_public, :title, :id)
```

But in `post/index`, i don't need to require these parameters.

How do you make different requirements strong parameters for different controller methods?

Answer (score 12):

Your "strong parameters methods" are just Ruby methods. You can have however many you want.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.new(create_params)
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(update_params)
      # ...
    else 
      # ...
    end
  end

  private

  def base_params
    params.require(:post)
  end
  
  # Don't take IDs from the user for assignment!
  def update_params
    base_params.permit(:body, :title)
  end

  def create_params
    base_params.permit(:body, :title, :foo, :bar)
  end
end
```

You can also name them whatever you want. Calling it `[resource_name]_params` is just a scaffolding convention.

Answer (score 2):

Just do something like

```
class FooController < ApplicationController


  def create
    @post = Post.new(create_params)
    if @post.save
      blah
    else
      blah
    end
  end

  def index
    ... something else
  end

private

  def create_params 
    params.require(:post).permit(:body, :is_public, :title, :id)
  end

end
```